# Increase size of my code font - DWCS5

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver

I'm trying to do something pretty basic here. I just want to make the font of my code larger so I can see it better. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences, Fonts

Answer (score 5):

In DreamWeaver CS6 Option are changed, On the left hand top side on the screen

```
Dreamweaver > Preference > Fonts > Code view
```

This image display where to change fonts..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **CS5** most importantly on Windows the preference option is under the edit menu. Where font category contains the option of code view font size. Its normally 9px. You can change it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to increase font size and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the font size.